# Async commits associated to a KafkaListener are not retried in case of RetriableCommitFailedException

Tags: spring-kafka

Async commits associated to a KafkaListener are not retried in case of RetriableCommitFailedException whereas this is the case for sync commits (based on ContainerProperties#commitRetries).

Is there any reason/constraint not to do this for asynchronous commits as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It caused problems because we ended up committing old offsets for partitions that already had later offsets committed. It could also cause stack overflows with large failure rates.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2088

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Perhaps a naive approach, but to avoid problems, wouldn't it be possible to delegate to a commit handler. This handler could then decide to either process or reprocess the latest registered commits. In brief, the handler would invalidate a reprocessing if new commits are available or if the retry policy is exhausted. The handler could also keep a “global” counter with a limit to avoid infinite consecutive retries. Having dropped the support is safer but this may cause a reprocessing of a bunch of records in some situations.

Comment: Unfortunately, the commits have to happen on the consumer thread; see `KafkaConsumer.aquire()`. I am not saying it can't be reinstated somehow but it will require some complex logic to keep track of the last successful commit for each partition and discard any retries that are prior to that, and maybe pause the consumer while there are retryable commits present (we do similar for out of order commits). Given the severity of the problem (including stack overflows) we decided the most expedient solution was to remove the retries. We can revisit, but with no timeline. Contributions accepted :)